# Multiplayer Game History database modeling

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I am trying to figure out how would I go about modeling a database that keeps track of Game history. 
In the game history, there can be a player 1 and player 2. 
I want to have a one to many relationship from user to Game history in both player 1 and player 2 columns. Am I going about this the wrong way? If so, what better way could I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using NoSQL database for the game. Use a state management architecture and you will be able to store your game state including all elements and players information such as (position, health, weapons... etc)

A simple 2D game state would something like this

```
interface GameState {
  grid: Tile[][];
  player1: Player;
  player2: Player;
  time: Date;
  state: string;
}

interface Player {
   position: Tile;
   health: number;
   weapons: Weapon[];
}

interface Tile {
   x: number;
   y: number;
   walkable: boolean;
   sprite: string;
   type: string;
}
```

Have a look at this game
[Demo](https://murhafsousli.github.io/runman/) | [Source code](https://github.com/MurhafSousli/runman/tree/master/src/app)

Comment: Thank you, i'm pretty deep in now though. I want to finish what I have and then later on optimize.